# Sort the table and change the ranks accordingly when a new row is inserted

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in my database:

```
id  userid  totalpoints  ranks
1    142        50       2
2    143        60       1
3    144        40       3
```

No if I want to insert a new row, suppose

```
4  145  55
```

Now how to insert that row and change the ranks accordingly based on the total points using mysqli and php?

In order to get the following output:

```
   id  userid  totalpoints  ranks
    2    143        60       1
    4    145        55       2
    1    142        50       3
    3    144        40       4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store `ranks` in your database, because this is derived value. Instead, use

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY totalpoints DESC
```

when you need that data. This will get you the scores ordered by points from high to low.

Comment: Indeed a better approach.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I made it more complicated, removing ranks column would solve my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
    userid,
    totalpoints
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY totalpoints) ranks
  FROM users
```

You can use this sql query to get output.